# Exlude some values in a matrix then compute the variance

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix X which has dimension 1000*16001. I want to exlude any values in this matrix that are greater than or equal 1 or smaller than or less than -1. Then computing the variance over the second dimension. My code is

```
[L,K]=size(X); 
        for n=1:K    
            for m=1:L
                if (X(m,n)>=1 || X(m,n)<=-1)
                    X(m,n)=NaN;
                end
                 varx=var(X(:,n),1,1,'omitnan');
            end

        end
```

Then plot the variance.

```
plot(T,varx','k','linewidth',2)
```

where T is time which has dimension 16001*1. However I get this error

```
Too many input arguments
varx=var(X(:,n),1,1,'omitnan');
```

How can fix this error and plot the variance over the time T. Many thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The following should delete all the values greater than 1 or smaller than -1:

```
Xnew = X;
Xnew(X > 1 | X < -1) = NaN;
```

Next, the variance along each row can be calculated using:

```
varx = var(Xnew,[],2,'omitnan’)
```

The plot, then, should not be a problem for you:

```
plot(T,varx,'k','linewidth',2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Still the same error appears

Comment: @David do you use 2014b or earlier? The `’omitnan’` flag was introduced in 2015a. Check the version using `version`

Comment: I am using 2014a. I updated Matlab to 2017a version and my code works perfectly. Thank you for your valuable comments.